# В этом доме никому ни/не жарко, ни/не холодно

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> В этом доме никому ни жарко, ни холодно.

> В этом доме никому не жарко, не холодно.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос правильности, когда нет контекста, вторичен. Тем не менее...

Если нужно было показать, что каждый находящийся *в этом доме* по какой-то причине **ни с того ни с сего** становится апатичен ко всему на свете, то «*ни холодно ни жарко*» как фразеологический оборот может это состояние передать без запятых. Останется заменить *никому* на *любому*/*всякому*/*всем*, ибо сочетание типа «никому всё равно» не несёт смысла, ведь ощущение не существует само по себе — только в ком-то.

Если говорить о доме не из сказки, при этом использовать слова из оборота, то необходимо либо взять их в кавычки, показывая, что не о безразличии речь — о градусах (если стиль позволяет), либо нарушить его конструкцию: ***никому не бывает жарко или холодно*** / ***никому не будет жарко, не будет и холодно***.

Comment: Интересный ответ, голос от меня. Я бы вот что добавила. Никому ни жарко ни холодно — это всем безразлично (фразеология).  Переносный отчасти смысл. А во втором случае можно так написать: никому не жарко и не холодно, нормальная температура. Это обычное усиление отрицания.

Comment: Простите, но *никому* никак не *все*. А про второй случай... Хотел было про температуру, но громоздкое что-то выходило. Щас вставлю.

Comment: А как сказать: В этом "доме" всем и все  безразлично?  Почти по теме, очень актуально)) Во втором случае я тоже про температуру, как вариант записи.

Comment: Надо «въехать» в эту сказку по уши, тогда и НИКОМУ место найдётся, а пока что **каждому/любому/всякому/всем** по-любому.

Comment: Я хочу фразеологизм использовать для своей мысли)  Как записать? В принципе это уже отдельный вопрос, так что можно задать)  Но мне никто не отвечает, увы!